# How do I put this code into one print function (or line)?

Tags: python, random

So I want to make this code into a single line. I have no idea how to create two random lists and then print out the common numbers that are in the two lists all within one line. I am new to putting code into one line and I have no idea if this is possible.

Here is the code that I have:

```
import random
a, b = random.sample(range(1, 50), 30), random.sample(range(1, 50), 30)

print([x for x in a for y in b if x == y])
```

And here is my try at this:

```
import random
print([[a = random.sample(range(1, 50), 30)], [b = random.sample(range(1, 50), 30)], x for x in a for y in b if x == y])
```

Comment: The issue certainly seems to be resolved, please mark any of the correct answers as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just embed the definitions since there's no need for a variable:

```py
import random
print([x for x in random.sample(range(1, 50), 30) for y in random.sample(range(1, 50), 30) if x == y])
```

You can also replace `random` with `__import__("random")` then get rid of the `import random` on the first line if you want a true one-liner.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is so logical.

Answer (score 3):

With sets:

```
>>> import random
>>> {*random.sample(range(1, 50), 30)}.intersection({*random.sample(range(1, 50), 30)})
```